# How to install spinnaker on local kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm trying to install spinnaker on local kubernetes cluster.

I found some guide at https://github.com/kenzanlabs/spinikube but this guide is out of date. Now all install and config spinnaker via halyard.

I also found this guide https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/quickstart/halyard-gke/ to deploy spinnaker on google kubernetes cloud using google storage.

But I have local kubernetes cluster on my data center, and I configured storageclass (via heketi and glusterfs) to persistent storage. Now I want to install spinnaker on my local cluster.

So can halyard support install spinnaker on local kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using Helm for this. [Helm](https://docs.helm.sh/) is a package manager for Kubernetes that makes installing applications in your cluster very easy.

Helm uses a packaging format called `charts`. A chart is basically a collection of files that describe a related set of Kubernetes resources.

There is a Spinnaker Helm Chart available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/spinnaker) that will install all Spinnaker services into your cluster with one command.

`helm install --name my-spinnaker stable/spinnaker`

Answer (score 0):

@Duong - You may try following this Spinnaker-helm repo to install Spinnaker Chart:
https://github.com/OpsMx/spinnaker-helm

This approach supports maintaining the local Spinnaker configuration in a GitHub repository.